# Accessing specific layers in ArcGIS Map Service to toggle them on/off?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, map-service

I have access to a number of ESRI Mapservices and would like to be able to access specific layers within the mapservices in my online map application. I am working on creating this with the ESRI Javascript API.

I have looked, at and hoped that I could use, this sample map:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/map/map_legendvisible.html

and substitute some of the data I have access to.

When I do substitute mapservices that we have here, the sample map will toggle on and off the entire mapservice and not the specific layer I was hoping it would.

Here is the mapservice I am trying to access with this code:

http://gis1.co.frederick.va.us/ArcGIS/rest/services/Planning/testplanning/MapServer

I would love to hear from someone about a solution. Nothing seems as straight forward as it looks...

Comment: i cant see that map service. I assume its dynamic and not cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that the class *"featureLayer"* can be used to display an individual layer within both a mapservice or a feature service..

[http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htmt](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm)

> dojo.require("esri.layers.FeatureLayer");
>
> The feature layer inherits from the
>   graphics layer and can be used to
>   display features from a single layer
>   in either a Map Service or Feature
>   Service. The layer can be either a
>   (spatial) layer or (non-spatial)
>   table. If the underlying layer (or
>   table) is from a Feature Service, its
>   features can be edited. ESRI-
>   Javascript API Reference

Here is the code I now have that utilizes this method.. and it works!!:D

```
var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://gis.co.frederick.va.us/ArcGIS/rest/services/Fire_and_Rescue/Fire_and_Rescue/MapServer/8",{
          mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
          displayOnPan:false,outFields: ["*"], opacity:.5, tileWidth:150, tileHeight:150, visible:false,
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });
```

Comment: You can also get the layerInfos of a dynamic layer, which will get you the id of each layer in the service and let you turn them on or off.

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code the quake, fire and base layers are three separate map services.
If you have a specific layer or layers that you want to toggle on/off using this sample, you can publish each layer as it's own map service, then plug them into your sample code.

Alternatively, if you want to have a list of the layers in your service and the ability to turn them off, these samples give examples of pulling a list of the layers in a service.

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/map/map_dynamiclayerlist.html

http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/map/map_explicitlayerlist.html

Comment: Zachery,Thanks for the info but I found a way to do what I wanted..

Comment: Although, I was unable to access the legend of the mapservice..